# graphql nested comments on each level

Tags: graphql, apollo, prisma

I want to make 2 deep nested comments system.

```
    getComments: async (_, { postId, take, after }, context, info) => {
      let queryRes = null;
      if (after) {
        queryRes = await prisma.comments.findMany({
          take: take,
          cursor: {
            id: after,
          },
          skip: 1,
          where: {
            postId: postId,
            parentId: null,
          },
          include: {
            author: true,
            children: {
              include: {
                children: {
                  include: {
                    author: true,
                  },
                },
                author: true,
              },
            },
          },
        });
      } else {
        queryRes = await prisma.comments.findMany({
          take: take,
          where: {
            postId: postId,
            parentId: null,
          },
          include: {
            author: true,
            children: {
              take: 3,
              include: {
                children: {
                  take: 3,
                  include: {
                    author: true,
                  },
                },
                author: true,
              },
            },
          },
        });
      }

      if (queryRes.length > 0) {
        const lastLinkResult = queryRes[queryRes.length - 1];
        const myCursor = lastLinkResult.id;

        const secondQuery = await prisma.comments.findMany({
          take: 1,
          skip: 1,
          where: {
            postId: postId,
            parentId: null,
          },
          cursor: {
            id: myCursor,
          },
        });
        const res = {
          edge: queryRes,
          comInfo: {
            endCursor: myCursor,
            hasNextPage: secondQuery.length > 0 ? true : false,
          },
        };
        console.log(res);
        return res;
      }
    },
```

This is my resolver, where I check if there's a cursor variable. If so - I response with a last cursor to make pagination. But, I want to make 2 times deep pagination with a cursor and a hasNext: true/false pagination, because I don't want to load whole comments in 1 take, so I take by 3 childrens.

```
  const A = gql`
    fragment A on Comment {
      id
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      authorId
      comment
      parentId
      postId
      author {
        name
        id
        image
        admin
        moder
      }
    }
  `;
  const getComments = gql`
    ${A}
    query GetComments($postId: Int!, $take: Int!, $after: String) {
      getComments(postId: $postId, take: $take, after: $after) {
        edge {
          id
          createdAt
          updatedAt
          authorId
          comment
          parentId
          postId
          author {
            name
            id
            image
            admin
            moder
          }
          children {
            ...A
            children {
              ...A
            }
          }
        }
        comInfo {
          endCursor
          hasNextPage
        }
      }
    }
  `;
```

this is my query, where I take childrens, on each children I want to get cursor and hasNext

```
type Comment {
  id: String
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
  authorId: Int
  comment: String
  postId: Int
  author: User
  parentId: String
  children: [Comment]
comInfo: commentInfo
}

 type commentInfo {
  endCursor: String
  hasNextPage: Boolean
}
```

Typedefs. So the question is - how can I get children on each level and get hasNext property to show it in frontend "load more comments" to the end user? do I need to manually map over children, make a query to the DB and add hasNext & endCursor property? because I think it is ineffiecient, or just don't care and load all comments? Thanks.